# mp3 to play in FireFox and in Chrome

Tags: javascript, php, firefox, audio, mp3

I'm extremely frustrated trying to get any mp3 player to play in Chrome and FireFox. I can get the one in Chrome to work but FireFox doesn't. How can I get an audio file to play successfully in both browsers? I only have an option for mp3 or wav as I am capturing a voicemail recording and then writing it to the server with the file name I wish. I presume ogg format wont work as I am writing the file as I am just using simply code like the one below:

```
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["recording"]["tmp_name"],"./" . $id . "-profile.mp3");
```

What can I do/use to get this to work right and get the mp3 to play on both browsers?

Comment: www139 - I actually just found a solution. Since it appears as FireFox needs the "ogg" file in order to play properly, I went on the hunt for an OGG API - and found this: https://cloudconvert.com Couple minutes of setup and it works and converts the mp3 to ogg for me easily! Hope it helps

Comment: Thanks I appreciate I'm actually not sure if my problem is with the file extension but I will work on it. Thanks for thinking of me. :-)

Comment: cloudconvert.com is definitely the way to go!